# Invalid Scopes public_actions error on facebook api integration in codeiginiter

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

I m trying to integrate `Facbook signin API` in my Web Application using `codeignitor`. I just need `user id`, `name` and `Email`.

According to documentation my requirements do not need any  access permission
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/overview/

But when I try to use `signin API` its gives me error as below

> Invalid Scopes: publish_actions. This message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

Comment: You get that error because you are asking for publish_actions permission. Don't ask for the permission and you will not get the error. You also need email permission to get email

Comment: Best copy and paste the error into your question, rather than use an image, because the link might later break.

Comment: Sir here is code i m requesting for feilds

    if ($this->facebook->is_authenticated())
  {
   // User logged in, get user details
   $user = $this->facebook->request('get', '/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name');
   if (!isset($user['error']))
   {
    $data['user'] = $user;
    $this->setSession($data);
    redirect(base_url());
   }else{
    echo 'user not set';
   }

  }

Answer (score 1):

Well i Found an answer 
in my config/facebook.php file

```
$config['facebook_permissions']         = array('public_actions','email');
```

i have chaged this line to

```
$config['facebook_permissions']         = array('email');
```

Now its Working Fine for me thank you